# Exceeded the maximum execution error when trying to delete multiple rows on given condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Currently, I am trying to do this with the following piece of code I managed to code :

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('***');
 var rowCount = ss.getLastRow();


for (i=1; i <= rowCount; i++) {

   var I = ss.getRange("I" + i).getValue(); 
   var J = ss.getRange("J" + i).getValue(); 
   var K = ss.getRange("K" + i).getValue(); 
   var L = ss.getRange("L" + i).getValue(); 
   var M = ss.getRange("M" + i).getValue(); 
   var N = ss.getRange("N" + i).getValue(); 
   var O = ss.getRange("O" + i).getValue(); 
   var P = ss.getRange("P" + i).getValue(); 
   var Q = ss.getRange("Q" + i).getValue(); 
   var R = ss.getRange("R" + i).getValue(); 
   var S = ss.getRange("S" + i).getValue(); 
   var T = ss.getRange("T" + i).getValue();
  if(I === 0 && J === 0 && K === 0 && L === 0 && M === 0 && N === 0 && O === 0 && P === 0 && Q === 0 && R === 0 && S === 0 && T === 0){

    Logger.log(ss.getRange("I" + i).getA1Notation());

    ss.deleteRow(i);

  }


}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the best way to achieve what I need, simply because the sheets I am working with are between 5-10K rows, therefore the script is exceeding the maximum execution time.

Can this be done in a better, faster and smarter way? And how?

Comment: Do each of those columns need to be `0` to delete the row? Is `0` actually in the cell? Or is it a blank cell? In other words, if even one column isn't `0`, you keep the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method in JS. It saves you from manually looping and testing each condition.

```js
function deleteRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Get all the data as a 2D array
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Go through each row in the array
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];

    // Test the row for *every* cell having 0.
    var toDelete = row.every(isZero);

    // If all columns in the row === 0, delete the row.
    if(toDelete) { sheet.deleteRow(i+1) }
  }
}

// Test 
function isZero(element, index, array) { 
  // returns true if each element in the array (the columns) === 0
  return element === 0 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function myDelete()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('***');
  var allshts=ss.getSheets();
  var sh=allshts[0];
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=vA.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
  {
    if(vA[i][8]==0 && vA[i][9]==0 && vA[i][10]==0 && vA[i][11]==0 && vA[i][12]==0 && vA[i][13]==0 && vA[i][14]==0 && vA[i][15]==0 && vA[i][16]==0 && vA[i][17]==0 && vA[i][18]==0 && vA[i][19]==0)
    {
      sh.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  } 
}
```

It's better to delete from the bottom to the top.

Comment: oops, sh.deleteRow(i+1); don't you think ?

Comment: Yep.  I changed it to (i+1).  Thanks